# program received signal SIGSEGV, segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c, linux, multithreading, unix

I am running a program in multi threaded environment it fails at some point. when i tried it with gdb than it is shoing the following error.

program received signal SIGSEGV, segmentation fault.

> [switching to thread 0x7fff677b700 (LWP 2777)]  0x00007ffff7aa42b9 in
>   process_incomplete_rows (resultset=0x507950) at c/mgmt.c:479 479
>   c/mgmt.c: No such file or directory.

mgmt.c file is there and this code is working fine for some options but 2 or three options its giving this error. What could be the cause of this error. Its error in comiplation or in coe? or its error while accessing some data?

Comment: add code with your question, segmentation fault is rumtime error not compilation time, you might getting warning at compilation time

Comment: You could get more information using `Valgrind` while running your app and by getting yourself a way to backtrace : (http://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/01/13/exceptions-stack-traces-c/). `Valgrind` would tell you in which case you are (writing past the end of an object, ...).

Answer (score 7):

A segmentation fault is a runtime error that is usually due to referencing an invalid pointer.  Usually that invalid pointer has never been initialized, but sometimes it is reusing an old pointer or writing past the end of an allocated memory chunk (such as past the end of a string).

Comment: In my case its due to problrm in reference? beacuse it is showing 79 c/mgmt.c: No such file or directory.

Comment: According to the error message, it's due to a problem at line 479 of the file `c/mgmt.c`. What is the code around that line?

Comment: if (node->result_row). where node it is a structure.

Comment: @user2298595 It's better if you post more code. But are you sure that node is not null?

Comment: So then `node` is an invalid pointer.  Most likely the code is working its way through a set of results and failing to detect that there are no more results.  Use a debugger to explore how the code is working and why node is getting an invalid value.  If you don't know how to use a debugger, then this is a great time to learn.

Answer (score 0):

It probably means that your `node` variable is either `NULL` or corrupted. Run your program in the debugger, stepping through it from some point prior to the crash up until it and see where you've messed it up. Or use one of the automated tools like Purify or Insure++ to track it down for you.